# Compare content of directories in Linux

Tags: linux, diff, ls

In Linux, if I have two directories, how I can see the differences of content in these directories?

Now I use this command:

```
diff <(ls -d dir1/*) <(ls -d dir2/*)
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `diff` on the directories themselves?

```
$ tree
.
|-- test1
|   |-- bar
|   `-- foo
`-- test2
    |-- baz
    `-- foo
```

The result:

```
$ diff test1 test2
Only in test1: bar
Only in test2: baz
```

Comment: I recall the `-r` flag being required in some cases...

Comment: Not if you want to mimic what the OP did, but I'll leave reading the manpage to them.